# how to know where is a propfile that is used by Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I have a problem which makes no sense at all. I inject a propfile for updating environment variable. However, it is not considered. An older propfile that I made 100 builds ago is used. I know because the value that is injected is a string not used anymore.

I'd need to find where it is taking the propfile it inject, which builds, which task, because it is for sure not using the one in the current workspace, because it has none of the content it injects.

I'm sure it takes it's content from a profile, because the variable is modified by the Injection of the propfile, and like mentionned, the value is one that hasn't been used for 100 builds.

If I write the content of the propfile to the console, it's clearly not what is injected. I made many tests

Answer (score 0):

Here is what happened and I made sure it was reported to Jenkins.

When you inject a file, Jenkins first look in the folder where it generates its Workspace, then it looks in the current Workspace.

The problem is that I had a propfile in the jenkins folder, the folder containing my current workspace. So it always used this one.

I reported it because it should at least be mentioned.